# RMI client in servlets UnmarshalException

Tags: jsp, servlets, permissions, rmi

I built an rmi application which searches file. It works fine on terminal. I wanted to give the search word thru JSP and wrote the client code in the servlet.

It is giving me the exception
     Exception occured: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myRMIImpl_Stub

I wanted to ask if I need to use policy file (which I was using in terminal)and stub file for client end. I copied the stub file in the classes folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to ask if I need to use policy file (which I was using in terminal)

You only need a policy file at the client if you are using a SecurityManager at the client.

> and stub file

The exception is telling you that you need it.

> I copied the stub file in the classes folder.

The exception is telling you that you didn't do that correctly.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Where should I put the Stub File? I have put it in the places possible in the netbeans project. Any ideas? I am using glassfish.

Comment: @shujaat You should put the stub file on the client's CLASSPATH, whatever that entails.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured it out. My mistake was I was using shujaat.client package and shujaat.server package. They both had to be same package name.

Comment: @shujaat your mistake was to try to put the same class into two or more different packages and then still assume that they would still be the same class. They aren't.